# Next.js: Prevent file (as Buffer) in response from being parsed as JSON

Tags: google-chrome, next.js, httpresponse, http-get

I have a server using the Next.js API, whence I want to send the frontend a .csv file encoded in a locale-specific encoding (Shift_JIS).

My server currently uses this approach:

```
download(res: NextApiResponse, buffer: Buffer, fileName: string) {
    res.status(200)
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/csv')
    res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="' + fileName + '"')
    res.send(buffer)
}
```

Looking at the logs in the server debugger, it seems that this part is working correctly.

The frontend page uses this code:

```
try {
    const response = await api.getRequestCsv({
    // insert necessary parameters here
    })
    console.log('tried', response)
} catch (e) {
    console.log('caught', e)
}
```

The API object does:
this.request<{
/* @format binary */
file?: File
},
any
>({
path: `/safdsfa/download`,
method: 'GET',
query: {code: '123'},
format: 'json',
})

The GET request sent in `api.getRequestCsv()` resolves correctly, but when I `console.log` it, I get this (abridged for brevity and secrecy):

```
Response {
    data: null
    error: "Unexpected token '�', "�v���W�F�N"... is not valid JSON"
    body: ReadableStream
        locked: true
    bodyUsed: true
    ok: true
    status: 200
    statusText: "OK"
    type: "basic"
    url: // insert intended URL here
}
```

My suspicion is that the frontend receives the response and, *somewhere,* it parses the file as a UTF-8 JSON string when it should have downloaded the stream as a file as-is.

How can I force the frontend to download the file in the response as-is instead of assuming that it's a JSON string and parsing it when it shouldn't?

Comment: Show us the "necessary parameters".  We can't tell, for example, if you accidentally asked for JSON processing.

Comment: @TimRoberts Added what the API is doing. You might have gotten me a clue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out. The server expects to respond with a JSON Object that contains a file, instead of directly responding with a file. I rewrote the backend response to:

```
download(res: NextApiResponse, buffer: Buffer, fileName: string) {
    res.status(200)
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/csv')
    res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="' + fileName + '"')
    res.send({file: buffer}) // changed
}
```

and did some complicated things in the frontend to extract the buffer from there and download it locally.